# QSslCertificate::importPkcs12 fails to parse PFX file

Tags: qt, sockets, ssl, openssl, pkcs#12

I'm trying to unpack my pkcs12 file in my Qt application - but having no luck. I'm building a **Qt Console App (GUI disabled)**.

(I've followed this guide: https://github.com/trueos/sysadm-ui-qt/blob/master/src-qt5/gui_client/SSLNotes.txt)

**Pkcs12 creation commands:**

```
"openssl req -newkey rsa:2048 -nodes -keyout test_key.pem"
"openssl req -key test_key -new -x509 -out test_crt.crt"
"openssl pkcs12 -inkey test_key.pem -in test_crt.crt -export -passout stdin -out new.pfx"
```

**Qt Code:**

```
QString password="1234";
QFile pkcs("/Users/test/Desktop/certs/new.pfx");
pkcs.open(QFile::ReadOnly);
QSslKey key;
QSslCertificate cert;
QList<QSslCertificate> imported_certs;
static bool import=QSslCertificate::importPkcs12(&pkcs,&key,&cert,&imported_certs,QByteArray::fromStdString(password.toStdString()));

pkcs.close();
qDebug()<<import;
```

Manually extracting the key and the file have worked using openssl commands.

**Error Message:**

```
"Unimplemented Code."
```

Any ideas?

Comment: What error are you getting? Can you describe "no luck"?

Comment: "Unimplemented code" and "false"... qDebug()<<import is returning the false..

Comment: What version of Qt are you using? `importPkcs12` was introduced in Qt 5.4.

Comment: If you are developing in Windows, the OpenSSL Toolkit must be obtained separately. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20351155/how-can-i-enable-ssl-in-qt-windows-application

Comment: @talamaki I'm developing on mac

Comment: Did you find the solution to your problem? I see in 1 of the answers that already a bug raised for Mac/iOS. BTW, I was wondering if we should send `QSslKey` as an empty object or need to fill something. To me the documentation of this function [`QSslCertificate::importPkcs12(...)`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qsslcertificate.html#importPkcs12) is not clear. Such as why do we have `cert` and `imported_certs`?

Answer (score 1):

Try using Qt < 5.6 like Qt 5.5.

In the Qt 5.6 the default SSL backend was changed from OpenSSL to Secure Transport on the Mac OS platform.

This problem already filled as a Bug: https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-56596

Answer (score 0):

| Platform | SSL Library | importPkcs12 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Windows, Linux, Android | OpenSSL | Supported |
| macOS, iOS | Secure Transport | Unimplemented code |

The above table should give you an understanding why you get "Unimplemented code" on macOS, iOS when calling `QSslCertificate::importPkcs12`.

For macOS, iOS, you *MUST* use "Secure Transport" SSL library else you may not be able to submit your app to the App Store.

[EDIT] This answer is old, and is based on Qt5.15.x and has not been tested for Qt6.x.

This answer is based on keeping "Secure Transport" as your default SSL library, but, also to statically link portions of the OpenSSL library so you can get the importPkcs12() functionality.

The following gives you a black-box wrapper to the importPkcs12() which switches between the two based on the platform you're on.

```cpp
#ifdef Q_OS_IOS
#define IMPORTPKCS12_OPENSSL
#endif
#ifdef Q_OS_MACOS
#define IMPORTPKCS12_OPENSSL
#endif

bool ImportPkcs12Patch::importPkcs12(QIODevice *device, QSslKey *key, QSslCertificate *certificate, QList<QSslCertificate> *caCertificates, const QByteArray &passPhrase)
{
#ifdef IMPORTPKCS12_OPENSSL
    return importPkcs12_openssl(device, key, certificate, caCertificates, passPhrase );
#else
    return QSslCertificate::importPkcs12(device, key, certificate, caCertificates, passPhrase );
#endif
}
```

For a complete working example, consult the sample here:

https://github.com/stephenquan/QtImportPKCS12

To build OpenSSL prerequisites for iOS and macOS, consult here:

https://github.com/stephenquan/build_openssl

Comment: importPkcs12 returns bool, so it cannot return "Unimplemented code". I'm currently having an issue with this function returning false on a production machine, when it returns true on the docker machine which supposedly reproduces the production environment. I really need to figure this out, and I've already explored every possibility so far (cert files checksum matches, password matches, I re-created the production environment from scratch). I really need to get an error message that would help me find out what's going on. How did you get this error message ?

Comment: @Michael "Unimplemented code" is shown to your error console whilst the function returns false, because, on macOS, iOS it is really is unimplemented. There's no default support for them. However, you haven't confirmed or denied if you're on macOS, iOS. If you're getting "false" on other platforms, it probably means that you have not deployed the SSL libraries for your platform. If it's a Linux distro, some come with OpenSSL 3.x libraries but do not ship OpenSSL 1.1.x libraries. e.g. https://askubuntu.com/questions/1403837/how-do-i-use-openssl-1-1-1-in-ubuntu-22-04

Comment: Thanks ! I've managed to solved the issue. It was a bit weird, because it turned out that OpenSSL 1.1 was already installed. Turns out I also needed a Qt plugin called libqopensslbackend.so. Specifically, I'm on Ubuntu 22.04. I'm positive it used to work fine around a year ago, but nowadays one needs to install the qt6-qpa-plugins package as well as the ssl libraries.