# How to install OpenSSL 1.1.0 for Qt on Windows?

Tags: c++, qt, visual-studio-2015, openssl, qsslsocket

My goal is to get the source code (or images) from a webpage over a SSL connection using `QNetworkRequest` with the `QNetworkAccessManager`.

**OpenSSL 1.1.0 doesn't work with Qt 5.8! Look in Edit 2 for the install solution!**

**First Try:** Get the ssleay32.lib and the libeay32.lib and copy them into the debug and the release folder. Dont work.

**Second Try:** (deleted because it's nonsense)
But it doesnt work again.

Code (works fine for normal http):

```
QUrl url = QUrl(name);
data.clear();

QNetworkRequest *request = new QNetworkRequest(url);
request->setRawHeader("User-Agent", userAgent);

QSslConfiguration sslConfiguration(QSslConfiguration::defaultConfiguration());
request->setSslConfiguration(sslConfiguration);

reply = webCtrl->get(*request);

connect(webCtrl, SIGNAL(finished(QNetworkReply*)), this, SLOT(replyFinished(QNetworkReply*)));
connect(reply, SIGNAL(readyRead()), this, SLOT(onReadyRead()));
connect(reply, SIGNAL(finished()), this, SLOT(onReplyFinished()));
```

Error Messages:

```
qt.network.ssl: QSslSocket: cannot call unresolved function d2i_DHparams
qt.network.ssl: QSslSocket: cannot call unresolved function DH_free
qt.network.ssl: QSslSocket: cannot call unresolved function d2i_DHparams
qt.network.ssl: QSslSocket: cannot call unresolved function DH_free
qt.network.ssl: QSslSocket: cannot call unresolved function d2i_DHparams
qt.network.ssl: QSslSocket: cannot call unresolved function DH_free
qt.network.ssl: QSslSocket: cannot call unresolved function SSLv23_client_method
qt.network.ssl: QSslSocket: cannot call unresolved function SSL_CTX_new
qt.network.ssl: QSslSocket: cannot call unresolved function SSL_library_init
qt.network.ssl: QSslSocket: cannot call unresolved function ERR_get_error
qt.network.ssl: QSslSocket: cannot call unresolved function ERR_get_error
Error creating SSL context ()
```

**Edit 1:**
I found [this](https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-52905) Artikel and OpenSSL 1.1.0 will be working with Qt 5.10 but not in Qt 5.8 what I am using.
And in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20351155/how-can-i-enable-ssl-in-qt-windows-application) Artikel I found the `QSslSocket::sslLibraryBuildVersionString()` command and I Need OpenSSL Version: `OpenSSL 1.0.2h  3 May 2016`.

I will checkout the other OpenSSL Version later and edit this post if it is working or not.

**Edit 2:**
Download `OpenSSL 1.0.2h  3 May 2016` and Install 7zip and Perl. Extract the openSSL folder and follow `INSTALL.W64`. Go to the `bin` folder and copy `libeay32-xxx.dll` and `ssleay32-xxx.dll` to the application folder and rename the files to `libeay32.dll` and `ssleay32.dll`. Thanks @[Max Go].

Now the SSL connection finaly works, but I get an error message when I Close the application and the web connection was used at runtime.

> Exception at 0x000000007772D1CB (ntdll.dll) in onlineTest.exe: 
>   0xC0000005: Access Violation reading position 0x0000000000000074.

VS2015 Debug Window "mem.c" line 443:

1. `free_debug_func    0x0000000000000000  void(*)(void *, int)`
2. `free_func  0x000007fee778b1ba {libeay32.dll!free}  void(*)(void *)`
3. `str    0x0000000002500cf0  void *`

**Edit 3:**
I forgot to compile the -d debug .dll's. Simply change the compiler mode to Debug, generate the Debug .dll's, rename if needed without the -d and then copy the debug .dll's into the debug folder and the normal .dll's into the release folder.

Comment: You are trying to copy static libs of openssl, but Qt needs dlls

Comment: As far as I can tell, Qt static builds are broken under MSVC 2015 and 2017 :( Your issue likely has nothing to do with OpenSSL. Remove the networking code and see if it still crashes.

Comment: @KubaOber my code worked find with MSVC 2015 and normal Networking (http). But since I added the `libeay32.dll` and the `ssleay32.dll` to the application Folder I have these crashes by exiting the application.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's the script I use to build OpenSSL automatically from a Visual Studio prompt. It will build either a 32 or 64 bit library, depending on what compiler is enabled.

Prerequisites (must be in PATH):

- Active Perl
- 7zip
- NASM
- Visual Studio 2015 or 2017 (I didn't test with anything else)
- jom (optional)

```
:: Configurable Options
:: If you have jom available, set it to jom - it speeds up the build.
@set JOM=nmake
:: Choose a static or dynamic build
@set LIBTYPE=dynamic
:: OpenSSL version in the 1.0.2 series
@set SRC=openssl-1.0.2k

@if "%VSCMD_ARG_TGT_ARCH%"=="x86" (
    @set BITS=32
    @set DST=OpenSSL-Win32
    @set CONFIG=VC-WIN32
    @set SETUP=ms\do_nasm
) else if "%VSCMD_ARG_TGT_ARCH%"=="x64" (
    @set BITS=64
    @set DST=OpenSSL-Win64
    @set CONFIG=VC-WIN64A
    @set SETUP=ms\do_win64a
) else goto no_vscmd

@if "%LIBTYPE%"=="static" (
    @set LIBTYPE=nt
) else if "%LIBTYPE%"=="dynamic" (
    @set LIBTYPE=ntdll
) else goto no_libtype

@echo Building %SRC% for %BITS% bits.

@echo - Downloading
@perl ^
    -e "use LWP::Simple;" ^
    -e "mirror('https://www.openssl.org/source/%SRC%.tar.gz', '%SRC%.tar.gz');"

@echo - Decompressing
@if not exist %SRC%.tar.gz goto no_archive
@rmdir /S /Q %SRC% %DST% 2>NUL
@7z x -bsp2 -y %SRC%.tar.gz >NUL && ^
7z x -bsp2 -y %SRC%.tar     >NUL && ^
del %SRC%.tar
@if errorlevel 1 goto unpack_failed
@if not exist %SRC% goto no_source

@echo - Building
@pushd %SRC%
@perl Configure %CONFIG% --prefix=%~dp0..\%DST% && ^
call %SETUP% && ^
nmake -f ms\%LIBTYPE%.mak init && ^
%JOM% -f ms\%LIBTYPE%.mak "CC=cl /FS" && ^
%JOM% -f ms\%LIBTYPE%.mak test && ^
nmake -f ms\%LIBTYPE%.mak install || goto build_failed
@popd
@rmdir /S /Q %SRC%

@echo Build has succeeded.
@goto :eof

:no_libtype
@echo Error: LIBTYPE must be either "static" or "dynamic">&2
@exit /b 1    

:no_archive
@echo Error: can't find %SRC%.tar.gz - the download has failed :(>&2
@exit /b 1

:unpack_failed
@echo Error: unpacking has failed.>&2
@exit /b %errorlevel%

:no_source
@echo Error: can't find %SRC%\>&2
@exit /b 1

:build_failed
@echo The build had failed.>&2
@popd
@exit /b 2

:no_vscmd
@echo Use vcvarsall x86 or vcvarsall x64 to set up the Visual Studio>&2
@echo build environment first.>&2
@exit /b 100
```

Comment: I think this should work fine with openSSL 1.0.2h for Qt 5.8. I installed it by hand and it works but unfortunately I have another problem...