# QT can't define references to Openssl

Tags: c++, qt, openssl

I already included *openssl* in my project in qt creator c++ in this way :

```
 INCLUDEPATH += C:/OpenSSL-Win32/include

 LIBS += -LC:/OpenSSL-Win32/lib -llibname
```

But when I try to use anything from openssl , qt gives me this error: undefined reference to `BIO_set_flags' *(and the same error if i try anything else )*

Comment: The openssl library is certainly _not_ called `libname`. You should put the real name of the library here.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how can I enable SSL in QT windows application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20351155/how-can-i-enable-ssl-in-qt-windows-application)

Comment: i include it in .pro in this way :
LIBS += -LC:\OpenSSL-Win64\lib -llibeay32
LIBS += -LC:\OpenSSL-Win64\lib -lssleay32